# multi level navigation menu in angularjs

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am writing a multi level dynamic menu which gets the menu data from the back-end and using UI LI tags I am building the menu items. The code for the same is as below:

**HTML**

```
<ul class="menu">
   <li ng-class="{ active: topController.currentMenuItem === item.Id }" ng-repeat="item in topController.menuItems">
       <a ng-click="topController.currentMenuItem = item.Id">{{::item.Title}}</a>
        <ul class="sec-nav" ng-if="item.SubMenu.length">
            <li ui-sref-active="active" ng-repeat="child in item.SubMenu">
               <a ui-sref="{{::child.State}}">{{::child.Title}}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

**Controller**

```
vm.menuItems = menuItems.data.Results.target0.menus;
```

**MenuItems returned from back end**

```
Fruits       Cars      Country       Hobbies   Weather      Dresses
 - Apple      - BMW     - England               - Autumn
 - Orange     - Audi    - Wales                 - Winter
```

The menu does builds and displays ok no issues, but issue I am having is with expanding and collapsing. When I click on any parent menu item, the sub menu items expands but when I click on parent item or any other parent item, the menu doesn't gets collapsed, it remains active.

I need to know, what changes I made to the code above, so that when I click on parent item, the sub menu item should get de-activated.

Also, I don't have any experience writing directives, so how to turn this piece of code in to directive, so that I can re-use this menu anywhere in my application.

Comment: Could you provide a plunker or jsfiddle?

Comment: Plunker link here: http://plnkr.co/edit/E5nPYYuabeNwizQfrhpe?p=info